# Changing localiztion in fragment activity android

Tags: android, localization

I try to change app localization in app. I try to change from action bar sub meniu:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
SubMenu langSelection = menu.addSubMenu(getString(R.string.message_lang));

            langSelection.add(getString(R.string.message_eng)).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new
                    OnMenuItemClickListener()
            {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("ENG");
                        try{

                            String languageToLoad  = "en";  
                            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);   
                            Locale.setDefault(locale);  
                            Configuration config = new Configuration();  
                            config.locale = locale;  
                            //getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,   
                           // getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());  

                            mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources()
                            .updateConfiguration(config, null);


                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        return true;
                    }

            });
            MenuItem subMenu1Item = langSelection.getItem();
            //setting pic for Actions
           // subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.icon57);
            subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

This code is in FragmentActivity. In minifest i had added:

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

But when i change lang this is not called:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("onConfigurationChanged() Called");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

I forgot something ?

Thanks

Comment: restart activity without animation.

Comment: I mean if your onConfigurationChanged() isnt calling then just do Intent intent = getIntent();
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
  finish();
  startActivity(intent);

Comment: Well it worked. But is there are no other solution